# Tag Editor- $(...).jsonTagEditor is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, tags, laravel-5.3

I just tried to implement the [json tag editor](https://github.com/alfonsomunozpomer/jQuery-JSON-TagEditor) to create a tag editor. 
I want to implement it in a bigger laravel project. Therefore I included jQuery, as well as the js and css file from the json tag editor. It's all loading fine, which I figured out under the network tab.

Now I have:

an input element:

```
<input id="keywords" class="form-control" name="keywords"
                                           autofocus></div>
```

and on top of the page I have:

```
$().ready(function(){          
     $('#keywords').jsonTagEditor();
});
```

But i get an error saying
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsonTagEditor is not a function`...

As I said, the files are loaded as I can see in the network tab...

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Again to make everything clear, I'm using laravel, so the files are all included in the master-layout file and I'm trying to use it in a document that extends this master template. But shouldn't change anything as I'm already using some other plugins that work fine that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Either you did not include the plugin or you loaded jQuery twice and the second one overwritten the plugin

Comment: @epascarello whats upi? and how do I otherwise include it

Comment: That `jsonTagEditor` thing is not part of jQuery; it's some sort of add-on.

Comment: @Pointy yes, that's why I included the js and css file of it

Comment: Well you didn't include it in such a way as to make it actually work. Does  the `<script>` tag that imports it come *after* the jQuery import? Have you checked for other errors when the page loads?

Comment: @epascarello jQuery seems to be only loaded once, in network tab I can only see it once, called jQuery-3.1.1.min.js and after it jquey.json-tag-editor.js

Comment: @Pointy yes, it comes after it and also network tab says that it's loaded after jquery

Comment: OK, well clearly *something* is wrong. From what you posted here it's not possible to say exactly what that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134850/discussion-between-nameless-and-pointy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion in chat, the problem turns out to be the suspected re-import and re-initialization of jQuery. The Laravel framework has it's own import of jQuery that happens via `require()`, and that was the happening after the plugin in question was imported.

Moving the plugin import to the end of the `<body>` worked around that, but in addition the plugin (as of this writing) has a bug and must be initialized with an empty object passed in (or probably any other value):

```
$("#keywords").jsonTagEditor({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `document` and just to be certain that the element is accessible, place your script before the ending `'</body>'` tag so that it loads your page content first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
    $('#keywords').jsonTagEditor();
});
```

Comment: Having `document` there is not necessary.

Comment: Well `$().ready(function()` is wrong, it should be `$(function(){ ... ` if he wants to use the short hand method.

Comment: No, `$().ready()` is fine. `$()` always returns a jQuery object, and the `.ready()` method always does the same thing regardless. I agree however that the simple `$(function() ... )` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write document

Instead of this

```
$().ready(function(){});
```

Use this

```
$(document).ready( () => {});
```

The `=>` means, that you use newest standarts of JS

Or you can just use [this alternative jQuery tagEditor](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-tagEditor)